# Joomla - Component URL rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting

I made an application in Joomla 3. Had a custom component in front end, which showing the details of a selected category.

**Which the URL with out enable search engine friendly and URL rewrite as follows**

```
wwww.sitename.com/index.php?option=com_arts&view=category&id=12
```

So I enabled the URL rewrite, SEO URL and URL suffix

```
http://www.sitename.com/component/arts/12.html?view=category
```

But I am trying to get a URL like this

```
http://www.sitename.com/caterory/12
```

I generated the link to this page using

```
<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=115&id='.$cat->id); ?>
```

Can anyone please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the SEF router do what you want it to do, you have [write your own router](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#Writing_a_router). You cannot, however, get rid of the component part of the URL.

Do do that, you do not need your own router, but a menu entry for each category. That menu does not have to be displayed, if you don't want to show it. The `alias` of that menu entry is then used for the SEF URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you are looking for

[Supporting SEF URLs in your custom component](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component)

[sef urls for custom component, which variant is better?](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2061824)